# Spotfire Bookmarks issue

Tags: bookmarks, spotfire

I have a dxp file published to Library (Server) having 5 dashboards.
All my filters are created using Document Properties for users to interact 
with.
I did the below scenario:

1. Selected certain values from the Properties so that data gets filtered 
   in reports.
2. Did the same in all 5 pages
3. Created a bookmark
4. Went ahead and made some more changes to the report. Selected another 
   set of values/changed the time frame
5. Did the same ini all 5 pages
6. Created a bookmark.

Now when I close the Analysis and reopen it, the latest bookmark gets 
applied to it by default. (I do not know if this is a feature).
When I click on the older bookmark, only first 2 pages reflect filter 
values properly. Rest reflect the New one.
When I re-did this, the last 3 were showing properly. First 2 had proper 
time range as well, but the product filters were wrong.

Does anything special need to be done for bookmarks?

Regards,
Subro

Answer (score 0):

The latest book marks are getting applied by default because it's the state where you last saved the dxp. You can click on the first book mark, save the dxp, and this will be what the users see when they open it on a Web Player.

Additionally, You can allow the users to return to the last "view" of the analysis /  where they left off if you change this setting:

```
Edit > Document Properties > Library (tab) > "Remember personalized view for each Web Player user"
```

It's hard to diagnosis the problem with the filters without seeing the dxp... but i suspect it is because of step 4, "Went ahead and made some more changes to the report". Depending on what you did, this would cause errors. Bookmarks aren't a snapshot of the memory...

Comment: Bookmarks store the document properties right. Are bookmarks per page or do they store for entire DXP file

Comment: No book marks aren't document properties. They store all the filter settings for the entire dxp. Think of it like a book part to a web page. If you create a book mark and then change a bunch of filters and then rever to the book mark everything will go back to how it was @Subro

Comment: I understand Bookmarks are not Document Properties. I mean just as it stores Filter values to allow a user to return to that state; I also believe it stores the values of Document properties. My only concern is that whether Bookmarks can store only one Page/dashboard related values at a time

Comment: Oh I see what you meant. And bookmarks are for the entire dxp not just a single page

Comment: Bookmarks should be saving Document Properties for the entire DXP